# json form for retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

```
[
    {
        "msg": "test",
        "time": "2017-06-20 00:39:31",
        "kind": "txt"
    },
    {
        "msg": "hi",
        "time": "2017-06-20 00:40:02",
        "kind": "txt"
    },
    {
        "msg": "url",
        "time": "2017-06-20 01:57:12",
        "kind": "img"
    },
    {
        "msg": "url",
        "time": "2017-06-20 01:58:54",
        "kind": "video"
    }
]
```

first sorry I am texting from a mobile phone .
second my question is , is this json for right for retrofit webservice to get msgs values in array and time in another array and kind in another array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear, could you explain what you're trying to achieve step-by-step?

I'm assuming that you're asking if you made "msg", "time" and "kind" in three different JSON arrays. In this case, no. What you are doing is creating objects that have the values of "msg", "time" and "kind" for the array that you did not specify.

Check w3schools on how to create JSON arrays and objects : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp

Updated answer for comment:

It would look something like,

```
{
 msg:[],
 time:[],
 kind:[]
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to receive this in android ? I can't figure out how my model will be like to get this response

Comment: Updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead.

```
msg:[ 
msgObject 
{ 
    msg: String,
    time: Date,
    kind: String
}]
```

I struggled with the same problem and was able to map it with POJO properly with above solution.